# Adding trend lines across groups and setting tick labels in a grouped violin plot or box plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, axis-labels, ggpmisc

I have `xy` grouped data that I'm plotting using `R`'s `ggplot2` `geom_violin` adding regression trend lines:

Here are the data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(value = c(rnorm(500,8,1),rnorm(600,6,1.5),rnorm(400,4,0.5),rnorm(500,2,2),rnorm(400,4,1),rnorm(600,7,0.5),rnorm(500,3,1),rnorm(500,3,1),rnorm(500,3,1)),
                 age = c(rep("d3",500),rep("d8",600),rep("d24",400),rep("d3",500),rep("d8",400),rep("d24",600),rep("d3",500),rep("d8",500),rep("d24",500)),
                 group = c(rep("A",1500),rep("B",1500),rep("C",1500))) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(time = as.integer(age)) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(group,time) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(group_age=paste0(group,"_",age))

df$group_age <- factor(df$group_age,levels=unique(df$group_age))
```

And my current plot:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=group_age,y=value,fill=age,color=age,alpha=0.5)) + 
  geom_violin() + geom_boxplot(width=0.1,aes(fill=age,color=age,middle=mean(value))) + 
  geom_smooth(data=df,mapping=aes(x=group_age,y=value,group=group),color="black",method='lm',size=1,se=T) + theme_minimal()
```

[image]

My questions are:

1. How do I get rid of the `alpha` part of the `legend`?
2. I would like the `x-axis` `ticks` to be `df$group` rather than `df$group_age`, which means a `tick` per each `group` at the center of that `group` where the label is `group`. Consider a situation where not all `group`s have all `age`s - for example, if a certain `group` has only two of the `age`s and I'm pretty sure `ggplot` will only present only these two `age`s, I'd like the `tick` to still be centered between their two `age`s.

One more question:

It would also be nice to have the p-values of each fitted slope plotted on top of each `group`.

I tried:

```
library(ggpmisc)
my.formula <- value ~ group_age
ggplot(df,aes(x=group_age,y=value,fill=age,color=age,alpha=0.5)) + 
  geom_violin() + geom_boxplot(width=0.1,aes(fill=age,color=age,middle=mean(value))) + 
  geom_smooth(data=df,mapping=aes(x=group_age,y=value,group=group),color="black",method='lm',size=1,se=T) + theme_minimal() +
  stat_poly_eq(formula = my.formula,aes(label=stat(p.value.label)),parse=T)
```

But I get the same plot as above with the following `warning` message:

```
Warning message:
Computation failed in `stat_poly_eq()`:
argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`geom_smooth()` fits a line, while `stat_poly_eqn()` issues an error. A `factor` is a categorical variable with unordered levels. A trend against a factor is undefined. `geom_smooth()` may be taking the levels and converting them to "arbitrary" numerical values, but these values are just indexes rather than meaningful values.

To obtain a plot similar to what is described in the question but using code that provides correct linear regression lines and the corresponding *p*-values I would use the code below. The main change is that the numerical variable `time` is mapped to `x` making the fitting of a regression a valid operation. To allow for a linear fit an x-scale with a log10 transformation is used, with breaks and labels at the ages for which data is available.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)

set.seed(1)
df <-
  data.frame(
    value = c(
      rnorm(500, 8, 1), rnorm(600, 6, 1.5), rnorm(400, 4, 0.5),
      rnorm(500, 2, 2), rnorm(400, 4, 1), rnorm(600, 7, 0.5),
      rnorm(500, 3, 1), rnorm(500, 3, 1), rnorm(500, 3, 1)
    ),
    age = c(
      rep("d3", 500), rep("d8", 600), rep("d24", 400),
      rep("d3", 500), rep("d8", 400), rep("d24", 600),
      rep("d3", 500), rep("d8", 500), rep("d24", 500)
    ),
    group = c(rep("A", 1500), rep("B", 1500), rep("C", 1500))
  ) %>%
  mutate(time = as.integer(gsub("d", "", age))) %>%
  arrange(group, time) %>%
  mutate(age = factor(age, levels = c("d3", "d8", "d24")),
         group = factor(group))

my_formula = y ~ x

ggplot(df, aes(x = time, y = value)) +
  geom_violin(aes(fill = age, color = age), alpha = 0.3) + 
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.1,
               aes(color = age), fill = NA) +
  geom_smooth(color = "black", formula = my_formula, method = 'lm') + 
  stat_poly_eq(aes(label = stat(p.value.label)), 
               formula = my_formula, parse = TRUE,
               npcx = "center", npcy = "bottom") +
  scale_x_log10(name = "Age", breaks = c(3, 8, 24)) +
  facet_wrap(~group) +
  theme_minimal()
```

Which creates the following figure:
[image]

Comment: This is great @Pedro Aphalo, thanks so much. Can I bother you to take a look at a related post I think you might be able to answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62986739/using-geom-smooth-for-fitting-a-glm-to-fractions?noredirect=1#comment111384559_62986739

Comment: @Dan I edited the title of your question here to make it easier for others to find. Will look at your other question in the evening.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution. The alpha - legend issue is easy. Anything you place into the `aes()` functioning will get placed in a legend. This feature should be used when you want a feature of the data to be used as an aestetic. Putting `alpha` outside of an `aes` will remove it from the legend.

I'm not sure the x legend is what you wanted but i did it manually so it should be easy to configure.

Regarding the p.values, i did separate linear regressions and store the p.value in three different vectors which can be called into the ggplot using the annotate. For two of the groups the p.value was <.001 so the `round` functioning will round it to 0. Therefore, i just added `p. <.001`

Good luck with this!

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(value = c(rnorm(500,8,1),rnorm(600,6,1.5),rnorm(400,4,0.5),rnorm(500,2,2),rnorm(400,4,1),rnorm(600,7,0.5),rnorm(500,3,1),rnorm(500,3,1),rnorm(500,3,1)),
                 age = c(rep("d3",500),rep("d8",600),rep("d24",400),rep("d3",500),rep("d8",400),rep("d24",600),rep("d3",500),rep("d8",500),rep("d24",500)),
                 group = c(rep("A",1500),rep("B",1500),rep("C",1500))) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(time = as.integer(age)) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(group,time) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(group_age=paste0(group,"_",age))

df$group_age <- factor(df$group_age,levels=unique(df$group_age))

mod1 <- lm(value ~ time,df\[df$group == 'A',\])
mod1 <- summary(mod1)$coefficients\[8\] %>% round(2)

mod2 <- lm(value ~ time,df\[df$group == 'B',\])
mod2 <- summary(mod2)$coefficients\[8\] %>% round(2)

mod3 <- lm(value ~ time,df\[df$group == 'C',\])
mod3 <- summary(mod3)$coefficients\[8\] %>% round(2)



ggplot(df,aes(x=group_age,y=value,fill=age,color=age)) + 
  geom_violin(alpha=0.5) + 
  geom_boxplot(width=0.1,aes(fill=age,color=age,middle=mean(value))) + 
  geom_smooth(mapping=aes(x=group_age,y=value,group=group),color="black",method='lm',size=1,se=T) + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c('','A','','','B','','','C','')) +
  annotate('text',x = 2,y = -1,label = paste('pvalue: <.001')) +
  annotate('text',x = 6,y = 10,label = paste('pvalue: <.001')) +
  annotate('text',x = 8,y = -1.2,label = paste('pvalue:',mod3))+
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]