# Using geom_smooth for fitting a glm to fractions

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, glm

This post is somewhat related to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62974766/removing-alpha-transparency-from-ggplot-legend-and-setting-x-axis-labels-to-be-f/62986181#62986181).

Here I have `xy` grouped data where `y` are fractions:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)

set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(value = c(0.8,0.5,0.4,0.2,0.5,0.6,0.5,0.48,0.52),
                 age = rep(c("d2","d4","d45"),3),
                 group = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C")) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(time = as.integer(age)) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(group,time) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(group_age=paste0(group,"_",age))
df1$group_age <- factor(df1$group_age,levels=unique(df1$group_age))
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to plot `df1` as a bar plot, like this:

```
ggplot(df1,aes(x=group_age,y=value,fill=age)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

[image]

But I want to fit to each `group` a `binomial glm` with a `logit link function`, which estimates how these fractions are affected by `time`.

Let's say I have 100 observations per each `age` (`time`) in each `group`:

```
df2 <- do.call(rbind,lapply(1:nrow(df1),function(i){
  data.frame(age=df1$age[i],group=df1$group[i],time=df1$time[i],group_age=df1$group_age[i],value=c(rep(T,100*df1$value[i]),rep(F,100*(1-df1$value[i]))))
}))
```

Then the `glm` for each `group` (e.g., `group` `A`) is:

```
glm(value ~ time, dplyr::filter(df2, group == "A"), family = binomial(link='logit'))
```

So I would like to add to the plot above the estimated `regression` `slopes` for each `group` along with their corresponding `p-value`s (similar to what I'm doing for the continuous `df$value` in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62974766/removing-alpha-transparency-from-ggplot-legend-and-setting-x-axis-labels-to-be-f/62986181#62986181)).

I thought that using:

```
ggplot(df1,aes(x=group_age,y=value,fill=age)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  geom_smooth(data=df2,mapping=aes(x=group_age,y=value,group=group),color="black",method='glm',method.args=list(family=binomial(link='logit')),size=1,se=T) +
  stat_poly_eq(aes(label=stat(p.value.label)),formula=my_formula,parse=T,npcx="center",npcy="bottom") +
  scale_x_log10(name="Age",labels=levels(df$age),breaks=1:length(levels(df$age))) +
  facet_wrap(~group) + theme_minimal()
```

Would work but I get the error:

```
Error in Math.factor(x, base) : ‘log’ not meaningful for factors
```

Any idea how to get it right?

Comment: To do a group by regression, you can do `df1 %>% group_by(group) %>% nest %>% mutate(model = map(data, ~ glm(value ~ time, family = binomial(link = 'logit'), data = .x) %>% tidy %>% slice(-1) %>% select(estimate, p.value))) %>% ungroup %>% unnest(c(model)) %>% unnest(c(data))`

Comment: I don't understand why you're using `scale_x_log10()` ... ???

Comment: @Ben Bolker - don't worry about the `scale_x_log10()`. I think that it may place the bars at their `time` numeric locations but display their `age' labels

Comment: the reason I was worrying is that I believe that's the proximal cause of your error.

Comment: The error occurs even if the `stat_poly_eq` and `scale_x_log10` lines are commented out

Comment: @dan If you map a factor to the x aesthetic ggplot2 creates a group for each level of the factor. Most ggplot statistics are designed to handle data by group, and  "see" only the values for individual groups. So, say if the aim is to fit an ANOVA to test differences among groups in a panel, the statistic has to be designed differently (somehow outside the normal expectations of ggplot2) and work on data subsets corresponding to panels rather than data subsets for groups. Some of the statistics in package 'ggpmisc' like `stat_fit_tb()` work in this way, but not `stat_poly_eq()`.

Comment: @dan So if you want a regression to be fit the explanatory variable must be continuos (numeric) while if the explanatory variable is a factor the levels are compared using ANOVA. This is how model fitting works in R and unrelated to 'ggplot2' although it affects the behavior of stat_smooth() and other ggplot statistics that rely on fitting models to data.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this could help:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

df2$value <- as.numeric(df2$value)

#Estimate coefs
dfmodel <- df2 %>% group_by(group) %>%
  do(fitmodel = glm(value ~ time, data = .,family = binomial(link='logit')))
#Extract coeffs
dfCoef = tidy(dfmodel, fitmodel)
#Create labels
dfCoef %>% filter(term=='(Intercept)') %>% mutate(Label=paste0(round(estimate,3),'(p=',round(p.value,3),')'),
                                                  group_age=paste0(group,'_','d4')) %>%
  select(c(group,Label,group_age)) -> Labels
#Values
df2 %>% group_by(group,group_age) %>% summarise(value=sum(value)) %>% ungroup() %>%
  group_by(group) %>% filter(value==max(value)) %>% select(-group_age) -> values
#Combine
Labels %>% left_join(values) -> Labels
Labels %>% mutate(age=NA) -> Labels
#Plot
ggplot(df2,aes(x=group_age,y=value,fill=age)) +
  geom_text(data=Labels,aes(x=group_age,y=value,label=Label),fontface='bold')+
  geom_bar(stat='identity')+
  facet_wrap(.~group,scales='free')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Pedro Aphalo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2419892/pedro-aphalo) this is nearly a complete solution:

Generate the `data.frame` with the fractions (here use `time` as an integer by deleting `"d"` in `age` rather than using `time` as the `levels` of `age`):

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)

set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(value = c(0.8,0.5,0.4,0.2,0.5,0.6,0.5,0.48,0.52),
                 age = rep(c("d2","d4","d45"),3),
                 group = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C")) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(time = as.integer(gsub("d","",age))) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(group,time) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(group_age=paste0(group,"_",age))
df1$group_age <- factor(df1$group_age,levels=unique(df1$group_age))
```

Inflate `df1` to 100 observations per each `age` in each `group` but specify `value` as an `integer` rather than a `binary`:

```
df2 <- do.call(rbind,lapply(1:nrow(df1),function(i){
  data.frame(age=df1$age[i],group=df1$group[i],time=df1$time[i],group_age=df1$group_age[i],value=c(rep(1,100*df1$value[i]),rep(0,100*(1-df1$value[i]))))
}))
```

And now plot it using `geom_smooth` and `stat_fit_tidy`:

```
ggplot(df1,aes(x=time,y=value,group=group,fill=age)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  geom_smooth(data=df2,mapping=aes(x=time,y=value,group=group),color="black",method='glm',method.args=list(family=binomial(link='logit'))) +
  stat_fit_tidy(data=df2,mapping=aes(x=time,y=value,group=group,label=sprintf("P = %.3g",stat(x_p.value))),method='glm',method.args=list(formula=y~x,family=binomial(link='logit')),parse=T,label.x="center",label.y="top") +
  scale_x_log10(name="Age",labels=levels(df2$age),breaks=unique(df2$time)) +
  facet_wrap(~group) + theme_minimal()
```

Which gives (note that the `scale_x_log10` is mainly a cosmetic approach to presenting the x-axis as `time` rather than `levels` of `age`):

[image]

The only imperfection is that the p-values seem to appear messed up.